# three.js - Do THREE.ShaderSkin supports displacementMap?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl, skin

I've tried to render a face model with `THREE.ShaderSkin` both with `skin` or `beckmann` variants.

In both cases I cannot seem to be able to add a displacment map (a bump map is used in the beckmann example in threejs page but that disables the ability to use normal maps, which I also wanted - in fact I wanted displacement+normal).

Is there any way for me to enable it, or any advice on how a shader noob to start to change/update those shaders with the new displacement map code?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possibly of some use: https://github.com/Brenden-Morales/Three.js-Materials-Test

Comment: thanks for the info. maybe adding it manually is the way to go!